# Java UTF-16 String always use 4 bytes instead of 2 bytes

Tags: java, string, unicode, character, utf-16

I have a simple test

```
@Test
public void utf16SizeTest() throws Exception {
    final String test = "п";
    // 'п' = U+043F according to unicode table
    // 43F to binary = 0100 0011 1111 (length is 11)
    // ADD '0' so length should be = 16
    // 0000 0100 0011 1111
    // 00000100(2) 00111111(2)
    //    4(10)  63(10)
    final byte[] bytes = test.getBytes("UTF-16");
    for (byte aByte : bytes) {
        System.out.println(aByte);
    }
}
```

As you can see I firstly convert 'п' to binary and then add as many empty bites while `length != 16`.

A expect that output will be `4 , 63`

But actual one was:

```
-2
-1
4
63
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte_order_encoding_schemes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you try:

```
final String test = "ппп";
```

you will find `-2 -1` only appears at the beginning:

```
-2
-1
4
63
4
63
4
63
```

-2 is `0xFE` and -1 is `0xFF`.  Together, they form a [`BOM (Byte_order_mark)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16):

> In UTF-16, a BOM (U+FEFF) may be placed as the first character of a
>   file or character stream to indicate the endianness (byte order) of
>   all the 16-bit code units of the file or stream. If an attempt is made
>   to read this stream with the wrong endianness, the bytes will be
>   swapped, thus delivering the character U+FFFE, which is defined by
>   Unicode as a "non character" that should never appear in the text.

`test.getBytes("UTF-16");` defaults to using Big Endian when encoding the bytes, so a BOM is included in front so later processors can know that Big Endian was used.

You can explicitly specify endian by using  [`UTF-16LE` or `UTF-16BE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) instead, thus avoiding a BOM in the output:

```
final byte[] bytes = test.getBytes("UTF-16BE");
```

> The `UTF-16` charsets use sixteen-bit quantities and are therefore sensitive to byte order. In these encodings the byte order of a stream may be indicated by an initial *byte-order mark* represented by the Unicode character `'\uFEFF'`. Byte-order marks are handled as follows:
>
> - When decoding, the `UTF-16BE` and `UTF-16LE` charsets interpret the initial byte-order marks as a `ZERO-WIDTH NON-BREAKING SPACE`; **when encoding, they do not write byte-order marks**.
> - When decoding, the `UTF-16` charset interprets the byte-order mark at the beginning of the input stream to indicate the byte-order of the stream but defaults to big-endian if there is no byte-order mark; **when encoding, it uses big-endian byte order and writes a big-endian byte-order mark**.

Comment: I'd like to highlight the fact that starting from Java 7, there is a class called `java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets` that brings his pack of constants for each charset that is often used. It prevents all typo errors in the charsetName.

Charsets exposed:

* US-ASCII
* ISO-8859-1
* UTF-8
* UTF-16BE
* UTF-16LE
* UTF-16